# Replace Dash (-) and Underscore ( _ ) with Space

Tags: plugins, php, regex

I want to replace dashes & underscores with space in this image file name:

**text1_text2-10212-etc_125.jpg** (result of a plugin)

My code is: `$string = preg_replace('/[\-_]/',' ', $file['name']);`

I'm trying with `str_replace` & `preg_replace` but it doesn't work. This code is part of the Advanced Image Grabber plugin ( in `class_image_grabber.php`)

```
//takes an image url as argument and save is to media library
// return Null on failure
static public function imageUpload($imageUrl) {
    $file = array();
    $file['name'] = basename($imageUrl);
    $file['tmp_name'] = download_url($imageUrl);
    if (is_wp_error($file['tmp_name'])):
    @unlink($file['tmp_name']);
    return NULL;
    endif;
    $attachmentId = media_handle_sideload($file, 0);
    // create the thumbnails
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachmentId,  get_attached_file($attachmentId));
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachmentId,  $attach_data );
    return $attachmentId;   
}//EOF
```

Comment: `$string = str_replace( array( '-', '_' ), ' ' , $file['name'] );`. But remember that these changes will disappear after plugin update.

Comment: did'nt work. the result is text1-text2-10212-etc_125.jpg. if I remove a space the result is : text1text210212etc125.jpg . 
2 years is not updated. maybe the author forgot this plugin: D

Comment: What does `echo $file['name'];` prints out?

Answer (score -1):

```
$file_name = "text1_text2-10212-etc_125.jpg";
$result = preg_replace("/[\-_]/", " ", $file_name);
ECHO $result;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
text1 text2 10212 etc 125.jpg
```

[Link for DEMO](https://eval.in/1030844)

Comment: The question already includes that line of code. They already know that part. The part they're asking about is doing it in the context of an image uploaded by a plugin. This answer does not address the actual question.